# Area inside the Cardoid and outside the Circle

Tags: integration

Find the area lying inside the cardoid $r = a(1 + cos \theta)$ and outside the circle $r = a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a fairly straightforward computation.  Where do you have difficulty?

The first thing I would do is determine the points where the two curves intersect to get the limits of integration on $\theta$.  That turns out to be simple:  $r= a(1+ cos(\theta)= a$ so $1+ cos(\theta)= 1$, $cos(\theta)= 0$, $\theta= -\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta= \frac{\pi}{2}$.
The "differential of area" in polar coordinates is $rdrd\theta$ so the integral is $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_a^{a(1+ cos(\theta))} rdrd\theta= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \left[\frac{1}{2}r^2\right]_{a}^{a(1+ cos\theta))}d\theta$
$= \frac{1}{2}a^2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (1+ cos(\theta))^2- 1)dr= \frac{1}{2}a^2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}2cos(\theta)+ cos^2(\theta) d\theta$.

Surely you can finish that yourself?

Comment: Yup, thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the graph of the functions, 
 [image]

(I've taken $a=1$ just for drawing graph).

Our desired area is the region between the circle and the cardioid on the right side.

Thus we confine attention to $\theta$ going from $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The area inside the half-circle is $\frac{\pi}{2}a^2$. The area of the part of the cardioid from $\theta=\frac{-\pi}{2}$ to $θ=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}=\frac{1}{2}a^2(1+cos\theta)^2d\theta$$

Calculate this integral, subtract from $\frac{\pi}{2}a^2$.

Comment: Yes, I've taken $a=1$ for sketching the graph.

Comment: @Barry Cipra thanks for your correction.